# Eficiencia en Script de Ocultar

Tags: javascript

espero puedan resolver mis dudas, gracias de antemano.
Yo tengo un script con un boton que hace que los elementos que tengan cierta class="" se oculten y lo que pasa es que son muchos elementos y me estaba preguntando cual de los siguientes es mejor o mejor dicho cual me recomiendan:

1.-script (el que tengo)

```
function Ocultar() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ocultarimg');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

2.-script

```
  function Ocultar() {
var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.ocultarfight'),
    i = 0,
    l = myClasses.length;
for (i; i < l; i++) {
    myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
}
      }
```

3.-script

```
function Ocultar() {
    var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("ocultarimg"); //divsToHide is an array
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
        divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; // or
        divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
    }
  }
```

4.-script (este lo que hace es agregar un estilo +unico, en lugar de agregar en cada div)

```
function agregar() {
var newStylesheet = document.createElement('style');
newStylesheet.textContent = '.ocultarimg { display: none; }';
document.head.appendChild(newStylesheet);
  }
```

Comment: Si todos estos script funciona bien, hay que seleccionar la que mas se adapte a tus ecosistema de funciones: ya sea las funciones mismas o respecto a la página web. Todo depende del sentido de uso, la adaptación, la funcionalidad, y la optimización; ya sea del lado del usuario o como el funcionamiento interno. Yo elegiría el código más simple pero eficiente y entendible, como así también el que no interfiera con otras funciones adyacentes o importados...

Comment: Puedes hacer un experimento y ver cuál de las 4 formas toma más tiempo en completarse.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que tu pregunta esta basado en opiniones, por lo tanto esta fuera del reglamento de [so]. Puedes leer [example] para informarte

Comment: Mi duda era más en cuanto al proceso del script, por ejemplo en el que tengo que es el primero, creo que añade el estilo diplay: none a cada elemento, pero el cuarto script añade un estilo css. Seria mejor que solo añade un estilo único ".oculto{display:none;" el lugar de añadir style="display:none" a cada elemento?

Comment: Personalmente yo elegiría uno que haga referencia a la hoja de estilos: `elements.classList.add("miEstilo")` para poder trabajar mejor y mas ampliamente con el estilo y hasta múltiples `@media`